# a:hover issue on Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

The bellow code works fine on Chrome but the hover effect isn't being applied on Firefox.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp">
        1 Link
        </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
a:Link {
text-decoration:none;
color:#008B45;
}
a:hover {
color:black;    
}
a:visited {
color:#EE9A00;   
}
```

Any ideas on this issue?

Comment: are you sure you tested this for at least 2 times in Chrome? looks like Chrome sets the priority of `:hover` higher than `:visited` automatically no matter where it's declared, following the normal rule, the `a:visited` and `a:hover` have the same priority, so the last declared one will override the other.

Comment: @KingKing — Chrome obeys the spec, I just tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have visited the link in Firefox.

The `:visited` rule is applied after the `:hover` rule, so it overrides it.

Reorder your CSS so that `:hover` appears after `:visited` if you want the `:hover` style to apply to hovered, visited links.

Answer (score 0):

Set hover state below visited and it will work

```
a:Link {
text-decoration:none;
color:#008B45;
}
a:visited {
color:#EE9A00;   
}
a:hover {
color:black;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/58M6h/

Comment: yes, it was answered, while I've wrote my answer and preparing jsfiddle.